# LINQ: populate NotMapped field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join, complextype

When I try to populate a NotMapped field I have an error ("The entity or complex type 'MyTable' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query").

Here there is is my example: what is the error in my code?
And, is it possible to have the ExternalDescription populated without populate field by field?

```
public partial class MyTable
{
    public int MyTableId { get; set; }

    public int Table2Id { get; set; }

    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public String ExternalDescription { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyTable2
{
    public int MyTable2Id { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}


var records = (from t1 in db.MyTable
                join t2 in db.MyTable2 on t1.Table2Id equals t2.MyTable2Id
                select new MyTable
                {
                    MyTableId = t1.MyTableId,
                    Table2Id = t1.Table2Id,
                    Field1 = t1.Field1,
                    Field2 = t1.Field2,
                    ExternalDescription = t2.Description
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: looks like you can project it to anonymous type first, after `AsEnumerable()` (replacing `ToList`), you then project the result locally (using LinqToObject) to a list of `MyTable`.

Comment: Yes, @KingKing is correct, you can try this: `...select new { t1, t2.Description}).ToList().Select(x => { x.t1.ExternalDescription = x.Description; return x.t1}).ToList();`

Comment: Thank you @SlavaUtesinov: it works. Just a little note: you missed the semicolon after "return x.t1".
Great